# Read Key in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on the game "2048". How can I wait till the user pressed one of the arrows and than identify what arrow did he pressed.
Thank You

```
            bool game = true;

            while (Game)
            {
            //Read The Key Here
            if ()//The Key is Up
            {

            }
            else if ()//The Key is down
            {

            }
            }
```

Comment: Look up how to subscribe to KeyEventArgs... Learn how this works philosophically and you can apply it in other languages..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to XAML, try the [OnKeyDownHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Width="300" Height="20">
    Type some text into the TextBox and press the Enter key.
  </TextBlock>
  <TextBox Width="300" Height="30" Name="textBox1"
           KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler"/>
  <TextBlock Width="300" Height="100" Name="textBlock1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = "You Entered: " + textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

[Mark W's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464386/capturing-key-press-event-in-my-wpf-application-which-do-not-have-focus) answer provides a similar example.